# 4 players get 13 cards each - does player 1 and player 3 have the same event size

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, combinations

let's say

A = {player gets no spades}

The players are dealt one at a time, player 1, then player 2, etc...

So the size of A for player 1 is $\binom{39}{52}$ because you remove all the spades.

Is the size of A for player 3 the same? Or is it just $\binom{13}{13}$ because that would mean the last player gets all spades, so there's only 13 cards left for player 3. I feel like I'm thinking about that wrong though.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is easier to count the number of ways that the spade suit can be distributed.

Players $A,B$ could have 0-13 spades distributed between the two of them.

The probability that $A,B$ have $n$ spades between them

$P(n) = \frac {{13\choose n}}{2^{13}}$

In order for A,B to have the same number of spades, then

1) $n$ is even (wich happens with probability 0.5)

2) the suit splits evenly

$P(\text{even split} |2n)  = \frac {{2n\choose n}}{2^{2n}}$ which is less than $0.5$ when $n> 2$ (and equals 0.50 when $n = 2$) and less than 0.50 overall.

our rough sketch then is that an even split will happen less than $\frac 14$ of the time.

To put some numbers on it.

The probability that the any suit splits evenly is less than $0.5$

$\sum_\limits{n=0}^{6} \frac {{13\choose 2n}{2n\choose n}}{2^{13+2n}} \approx 0.155$